# Prevent Stretching image from uiimage in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimageview

[image]

*Code snippet*

> ```
>         self.newsImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,130)];
>         //set placeholder image or cell won't update when image is loaded
>         self.newsImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newsDetail.png"];
>         //load the image
>         self.newsImage.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageBig];
>         [imageBack addSubview:self.newsImage];
> ```

I have one image on 40*40 size but image view size 300*130. How to avoid stretching image.

I want center of the UIImageview.

**Thanks in Advance !!!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just center the content:

```
self.newsImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
```

Answer (score 1):

ou have to set CGSize as your image width and hight so image will not stretch and it arrange at the middle.

```
- (UIImage )imageWithImage:(UIImage )image scaledToFillSize:(CGSize)size
{
    CGFloat scale = MAX(size.width/image.size.width, size.height/image.size.height);
    CGFloat width = image.size.width * scale;
    CGFloat height = image.size.height * scale;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake((size.width - width)/2.0f,
                                  (size.height - height)/2.0f,
                                  width,
                                  height);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
    [image drawInRect:imageRect];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```